# Usefulness of return value not depending on all (exclusively call-by-value) parameters

Tags: c, function

I have one question:

```
int swapnum( int x, int y )
{
   int tempnum ;
   tempnum = x ;
   x = y ;
   y = tempnum ;
   return tempnum;

}
int swapnum(int, int);
int main( )
{
    int x = 35, y = 45 ;
    printf("Before swapping: %d, %d", x, y);
    swapnum(x, y);
    printf("\nAfter swapping: %d, %d", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

I have found this example in internet which demonstrates how call by value works. I understand everything except one thing. For what do we need call by value if we do not get changed result in main? I understood idea of call by reference; we will receive changed result but for what do we need call by value if result is changed only locally (in upper part of this code) and main stays unchanged (`printf("\nAfter swapping: %d, %d", x, y);`)?  And if you write your example too to demonstrate it would be great.

Comment: With call-by-value functions are more close to mathematical functions, and are then much more easily composed.

Comment: it allows you to send values without worrying that some function will change them. It's very convenient.

Comment: This example does not make any sense. It will be optimized out by any compiler

Comment: Read this https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23246/what-is-pass-by-value-result-and-its-advantage-and-disadvantage

Comment: How would you want `printf()` to change the variables in your code?

Comment: So it is bad example?

Comment: It's not necessarily a bad example. However, showing how call by value works and then drawing the conclusion that it is useless is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are even functions which do not return anything. 
They have a prototype like

```
void useTwoNums(int, int);
```

They illustrate even better than your example that it is not necessary to return anything, even less something which somehow uses the two input parameters and/or depends on them.

The concept which you seem to be missing is the difference between "functions" in mathematical context and "functions" in programming. In programming a function might well do something without returning something. One example is a function which just nicely prints the input values, compare `printf()`,
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf
Its return value can be handled inside the return-value-free function to illustrate.

The extreme case would be a function with neither parameters nor return value:
`void DoSomethingInFreespace(void);`. Functions like that can achieve the data to process e.g. via other input channels. Or they are simply refactored pieces of code, e.g. for reuse, which have a sufficiently rich context, e.g. global or file local variables.

To make the answer more complete, I will integrate some points from comments (including the one by OP, which focuses on return values):
*With call-by-value functions are more close to mathematical functions, and are then much more easily composed.* (Jean-Baptiste Yunès). 
and
*it allows you to send values without worrying that some function will change them. It's very convenient.* (njzk2)
Both (and other, too) stress that a mathematical function does not alter the parameters; this is something of a "promise" which programmers appreciate.

Turning it around:
*when using call by value if you want that [a value in the context outside of the function, e.g.] main be changed we must return the result* (OP)

Different angle:
*when using call by reference, we don't need to return; it [the parameter] itself changes [outside of the context of the called function and can be used as a] result* (OP)

Comment: oh so when using call by value if you want that main be changed we must return the result and when using call by reference we dont need to return it itself changes result.but it changes everything in main too.that's why call by value is more convenient , we will return answer which we got but in main arguments will not change.right?did I understand correctly?

Comment: oh thank you very much thanks.you helped me very much.))

Comment: @Yunnosch the new title is certainly catchier, but doesn't it change the meaning?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya First of all, thanks for your input. I am of course convinced that I did not change the meaning. But if you would elaborate and maybe point out which part I accidentally changed, then I will happily undo or improve. To explain, I am convinced that the question is caused by OP wondering/confused about this aspect of the chosen example.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I either spotted what you are referring to - or you caused me to find something separatly helpful. Thanks either way.

Comment: @Yunnosch sure, from the question I understand that OP is wondering why call by reference is not the default behavior in C. He/She is wondering what would be the usefulness of a function if it doesn't modify what is passed to it (this confusion is because they have seen functions like `swap` mentioned above, which obviously wouldn't work because of call by value). I am not able to see how the confusion is about return values depending on the arguments.

Comment: @ႨႰႠႩႪႨ Please comment on whether you like my new title. If you also think that it is missing the point, I will undo. You might want to find a better title yourself. If it is to the point and highlights the focus of your problem, it might be better appreciated as making a good question for the benefit of others. In that case you could attract more upvotes, in case you want to. Also, please take my apology if I was wrong.

Comment: @Yunnosch yes you are right it is much better I agree.perfect.)

Comment: @Yunnosch if OP confirms it, there is no doubt :)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Thanks, I am relieved. I will cleanup some of the comments soon.

Answer (score 0):

> I have found this example in internet which demonstrates how works call by value. I understand everything except one thing: for what do we need call by value?

You don't *need* call-by-value. But call-by-value is how C works, and most programming languages actually, so you would do well to learn it.

> I understood idea of call by reference, we will receive changed result but for what do we need call by value if result is changed only locally

Call-by-value is used in most programming languages because it makes it easier to think about the code. When you see `doStuff(x, y);` you know that `x` and `y` won't change. They can only change if you write `doStuff(&x, &y);` or `x = doStuff(y);` or something like that. You don't need go and look up the DoStuff Manual to find out whether `doStuff` is supposed to change them.

> and if you write your example too to demonstrate it would be great.

There's really nothing to demonstrate; the point of call-by-value is that nothing happens. Do you want a demonstration of nothing happening?

Answer (score 0):

The return value is useful when you have formulas.
If you want to calculate the hypotenus from the cathetus and you pass the value of the latters, you do not want theit value modified.